# Taking screenshot in different route in angular using protractor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, testing, protractor

I am new to testing using protractor so for testing I have to take screenshots in an angular application for all the different routes in my app. I tried to do it on a small dummy angular app, so I cloned the  [`Tour of heroes`](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-tour-of-heroes) repo it has dashboard and Heroes route. I wrote the following code in app.po.ts :

```
import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';

export class BlankPage {
  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get('/heroes');
  }

  getParagraphText() {
    return element(by.tagName('h2')).getText();
  }
}
```

and in app.e2e-spec.ts

```
import { BlankPage } from './app.po';
import {browser,by,element} from 'protractor';
import { protractor } from 'protractor';
import {createWriteStream} from 'fs' ;

describe('blank App', () => {
  let page: BlankPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new BlankPage();
  });

  it('should display message saying app works', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect(page.getParagraphText()).toEqual('My Heroes');
    browser.takeScreenshot().then((png) =>{
      var stream = createWriteStream("heroes.png"); /** change the png file name  */
      stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
      stream.end; 
  });
});
});
```

The idea was to navigate to heroes route and capture the screenshot. I got the screenshot but
Is there a way I can automate the task of going to all the routes and take screenshots ? In my actual website there are a lot of routes

Comment: Are you intending to do visual validation of the screens to ensure they look correct or do you simply need to capture the screenshot for some other purpose?

Comment: @DublinDev So first I am goig to take all the screen shots visually validate them and then saving them as the Golden image in our database. There will also be tests to take screenshot and test them aginst Golden images in future if we make changes in our website. I will be using Pixelmatch to check  difference between this current and Golden image (created before)

Comment: @DublinDev What do you suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the better solution for you is to add some reporter that will do everything for you, like taking screenshots after each test or after each failed tests and e.t.c.

Take a look at some reporters:

[allure-jasmine](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-jasmine) - Highly recommended.

[protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter](https://github.com/mlison/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter)

[protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter](https://github.com/Kenzitron/protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter)

[protractor-html-reporter-2](https://github.com/abhishekkyd/protractor-html-reporter-2)

[protractor-html-screenshot-reporter](https://github.com/jintoppy/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter)

[protractor-beautiful-reporter](https://github.com/Evilweed/protractor-beautiful-reporter)

But If you don't want to add any extra libraries to your project you can just put the `browser.takeScreenshot()` function to the `afterEach` function to take a screenshot after each test (`it`).

For instance:

```
describe('blank App', () => {
  let page: BlankPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new BlankPage();
  });
  afterEach(() => 
    browser.takeScreenshot().then((png) =>{
      var stream = createWriteStream("heroes.png"); /** change the png file name  */
    stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
    stream.end; 
    });
  });

  it('should display message saying app works', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect(page.getParagraphText()).toEqual('My Heroes');

  });
});
```

Comment: But after every test it will take screenshot and save it as heroes.png this way there will only be one image named heroes.png not different images for different tests

Comment: as I said it will be better to take a reporter and it will do it for, or you can get spec name and name it as your spec's name or route's name

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach for you would be the have a list of all the routes in your application and create a datadriven test to iterate over each one.

You would need a generic navigation function which could get to each page e.g navigateTo(routeName). That code would look something like this.

```
var routes = [
    'homepage',
    'myheroes',
    'mainpage',
    'heroprofile'
]

describe('blank App', () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {
        it('should display message saying app works', () => {
            navigateTo(routes[i]);
            browser.takeScreenshot().then((png) => {
                var stream = createWriteStream(routes[i] + ".png"); /** change the png file name  */
                stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
                stream.end;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

**protractor-image-compare**

Really though I would recommend you use the npm package [protractor-image-comparison](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-image-comparison). I've worked with this package and it does make visual validation very straightforward. It allows you to save new baseline images (golden images as you call them) if they are absent and compares them if they are present. The comparison are very sensitive to change but you can set how much of a difference you want to allow.

There would be no database required with this approach.

**Note**

Be aware also that different browsers take screenshots differently based. Chrome considers the "viewport" to be the visible portion of the browser but I believe in firefox you can screenshot the entire webpage at once.